# Swift @autoclosure parameter wraps provided explicit closure

Tags: swift, closures

Consider the following function:

```
func whatever(foo: @autoclosure () -> Int) {
  let x = foo()
  print(x)
}
```

Naturally, we can invoke it like this:

```
whatever(foo: 5)
// prints: 5
```

However providing an explicit closure argument causes the compiler to complain:

```
whatever(foo: { 5 })
// Error: Function produces expected type 'Int'; did you mean to call it with '()'?
```

Is this the intended? Reading the documentation for `@autoclosure` I did not find a statement about whether arguments are *always* wrapped, even when providing a closure. My understanding of `@autoclosure` was:
*Take a closure argument. If the argument is not a closure but has the same type as the closure would return, wrap it.*
However, the behaviour I'm seeing is: *Wrap the argument no matter what.*

A more elaborate example makes this seem very odd to me:

```
struct Defaults {

  static var dispatcher: Defaults = ...

  subscript<T>(setting: Setting<T>) -> T { ... }

  struct Setting<T> {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: () -> T

    init(key: String, defaultValue: @escaping @autoclosure () -> T) {
      self.key = key
      self.defaultValue = defaultValue
    }
  }
}

extension Defaults.Setting {
  static var nickname: Defaults.Setting<String> {
    return Defaults.Setting(key: "__nickname", defaultValue: "Angela Merkel")
  }
}

//  Usage:
Defaults.dispatcher[.nickname] = "Emmanuel Macron"
```

Now let's say I want to hash the key of a `Setting` value:

```
extension Defaults.Setting {
  var withHashedKey: Defaults.Setting<T> {
    return Defaults.Setting(key: key.md5(), defaultValue: defaultValue)
    // Error: Cannot convert return expression of type 'Defaults.Setting<() -> T>' to return type 'Defaults.Setting<T>'
  }
}
```

To clarify: `defaultValue` is of type `() -> T`. Providing it to `init(key: String, defaultValue: () -> T)`, in my expectation should just work, because the argument and parameter have the same type (while parameter is `@autoclosure`).
However, Swift seems to wrap the provided closure, effectively creating `() -> () -> T`, which creates `Setting<() -> T>` instead of `Setting<T>`.
I can work around this issue by declaring an `init` which takes an explicitly non-`@autoclosure` parameter:

```
extension Defaults.Setting {
  init(key: String, defaultValue: @escaping () -> T) {
    self.init(key: key, defaultValue: defaultValue)
  }
}
```

What's really daunting is that I can simply forward to the `init` taking the `@autoclosure` parameter and it works.

Am I missing something here or is it just not possible by design in Swift to provide closure arguments to `@autoclosure` parameters?

Comment: It seems like a syntax conflict. It would probably work with `whatever { 5 }`  (trailing closure) or `whatever { return 5}`.

Comment: Sadly no. Syntax seems right here. I get the same error with both of your versions.

Comment: You could just say `return Defaults.Setting(key: key.md5(), defaultValue: self.defaultValue())`, or `let defaultValue = self.defaultValue; return Defaults.Setting(key: key.md5(), defaultValue: defaultValue())` to avoid the capturing of `self`. In both cases, the closure call is wrapped in an autoclosure, so won't be evaluated until the default value comes to be used. AFAIK, the only time you can forward a closure to an autoclosure parameter is when the closure is `@autoclosure` itself, e.g `func foo(_ x: @autoclosure () -> Bool) {}; func bar(_ x: @autoclosure () -> Bool) { foo(x) }`

Comment: In both cases, `defaultValue()` evaluates the original closure just to wrap it again, doesn't it?

Comment: I've just verified this in a playground. You were right, it does not evaluate but wraps it. It seems you have to provide non-function types to `@autoclosure` parameters. If you cast your comment into an answer, I'm happy to accept it :)

Comment: Then again, why can I create an init that takes a non-`@autoclosure` and forwards to an init that takes a `@autoclosure`? There should be no difference in calling the `@autoclosure` init directly providing a closure, right?

Comment: @Cabus Looks like vacawama beat me to it :) I do agree it sure would be nice for `@autoclosure` parameters to accept closure arguments, but it could lead to some ambiguities in generic code and probably add complexity to the type-checker. Although btw, it looks like the ability to forward an `@autoclosure` parameter to another [is actually a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5719).

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for the insight. It looks like this could actually be added in the future, which I would agree would be nice. I rechecked my implementation and noticed that the compiler, type system and autocompletion already do a great job in telling you how `@autoclosure` should be used. If you look at the autocompletion box of, say `Setting<T>.init`, it clearly wants you to put in a `T` and **not** a `() -> T`. In the end, it was just a misconception on my side :). Thanks for helping out anyways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swift expects you to pass an expression that results in an `Int` to `whatever(foo:)` and Swift will wrap that expression in a closure of type `() -> Int`.

```
func whatever(foo: @autoclosure () -> Int) {
    let x = foo()
    print(x)
}
```

When you call it like this:

```
func whatever(foo: {5})
```

you are passing an expression that results in `() -> Int` and not the `Int` Swift expects.  That is why it suggests you add `()` and call that closure to get an expression that returns an `Int`:

```
func whatever(foo: {5}())
```

Note that since Swift wraps `{5}()` in a closure, it does not get evaluated before the call to `whatever(foo:)` but in fact the call is delayed until you evaluate `let x = foo()`.

You can verify this by running this in a Playground:

```
func whatever(foo: @autoclosure () -> Int) {
    print("inside whatever")
    let x = foo()
    print(x)
    let y = foo()
    print(y)
}

whatever(foo: { print("hi"); return 3 }())
```

Output:

> ```
> inside whatever
> hi
> 3
> hi
> 3
> ```

---

If you want `whatever(foo:` to also be able to take a `() -> Int` closure, overload it and call the autoclosure version after calling `foo`:

```
func whatever(foo: @autoclosure () -> Int) {
    print("autoclosure whatever")
    let x = foo()
    print(x)
}

func whatever(foo: () -> Int) {
    print("closure whatever")
    whatever(foo: foo())

}

whatever(foo: { print("two"); return 6 })
whatever(foo: { print("two"); return 6 }())
```

Output:

> ```
> closure whatever
> autoclosure whatever
> two
> 6
> autoclosure whatever
> two
> 6
> ```

Comment: *Swift expects you to pass an expression that results in an* `Int` *to* `whatever(foo:)` - Yeah. I get that now. However, it would be nice to have this hiccup documented somewhere. Anyway, I've learned something today.